# Docker image working with docker run but not with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi I am Facing Trouble with docker image

This is Dockerfile For Backend

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nano \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3-venv \
    mysql-client

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3.6-dev \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libssl-dev

# Clone the git repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/peyyala7hills/new_chatapp /app

WORKDIR /app

# Copy settings.py to the appropriate location
RUN rm /app/fundoo/fundoo/settings.py
COPY settings.py /app/fundoo/fundoo/

# Set up Python virtual environment and install dependencies
RUN python3 -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN cd ./fundoo && pip3 install python-dotenv

# Create systemd service file
RUN echo '[Unit]\n\
Description=Chatapp Service\n\
After=network.target\n\
\n\
[Service]\n\
User=ubuntu\n\
Group=ubuntu\n\
WorkingDirectory=/app/fundoo\n\
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "cd /app && source venv/bin/activate && cd /app/fundoo && /app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 fundoo.wsgi:application"\n\
\n\
[Install]\n\
WantedBy=multi-user.target' > /etc/systemd/system/chatapp.service

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# Start gunicorn server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /app/fundoo && /app/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 fundoo.wsgi:application"]
```

File for docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  database:
    image: database:v1
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: chatapp
      MYSQL_USER: chatapp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - volumedb:/etc/mysql
      - volumedb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - rajcharanmaster

  backend:
    image: backend:v3
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - backdata:/etc
      - backdata_config:/app
    networks:
      - rajcharanmaster

  frontend:
    image: frontend:v2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - frontdata:/etc
    networks:
      - rajcharanmaster
    environment:
      BACKEND_HOST: backend
      DATABASE_HOST: database

networks:
  rajcharanmaster:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  backdata:
  backdata_config:
  frontdata:
  volumedb:
  volumedb_data:
```

when i build the image with the above dockerfile it runs fine but when i try to docker-compose.yml it doesnt and i dont have an idea why

can anyone explain me please

I was Expecting that docker-compose run -d must work and launch 3 instances for frontend , backend , database but database and frontend just works fine

problem arises with backend only

i was getting mysqlclient issue in dockerfile but in image or run it was running fine

Comment: How do you run it without compose? What is the exact command?

Comment: can you attach docker logs

Comment: You're overwriting the `/app` directories in both containers with a volume mount, so the containers see what's in the volume and not the code or virtual environment built into the images.  Does deleting these `volumes:` blocks help?